# Error: *** Deployment Failed ***

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, infura, rinkeby, erc-721

I am trying to deploy my contracts, but I keep getting the same error message:

```
   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- sender account not recognized.
```

Here is my migrations.sol file:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is and could anyone assist me in resolving my issue?

Comment: Please share truffle-config.js, migrations scripts, other details required to reproduce the problem. What client is used? ganache, getch, besu, etc Which network is used? ropsten, rinkeby, goerli, or a private testnet.

Comment: This project is based on the open sea creature tutorial.
Migrations:
```
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }
```
I used Meta Mask on the Rinkeby network.

The tutorial I am referring to is https://docs.opensea.io/docs/1-structuring-your-smart-contract#section-minting-your-tokens